# Did Twain state: "Most people are bothered by those Scripture passages which they cannot understand...."

Tags: quotes

> Most people are bothered by those Scripture passages which they cannot
>   understand. But for me, the passages in Scripture which trouble me
>   most are those which I do understand.” –Mark Twain

I've seen the above quote bandied about often, generally by Christians for various effects. In my searching, I see that it is attributed to Twain but can never find a source. The most likely candidates seem to be "Letters from the Earth" or "Mark Twain's Notebook" but I cannot find any evidence that he actually stated such a thing.

Comment: Welcome to SE.Skeptics!  Since this board's about investigating notable claims, it's usually best to provide a link to a notable source of the claim being asked about.  This can be edited into the question statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[He probably didn't](https://www.good.is/articles/if-mark-twain-said-it-he-probably-didnt). There are slightly different versions of this quote out there, and the earliest example I was able to find appears to be [from 1931](https://books.google.com/books?id=pgL0AAAAMAAJ).

> Mark Twain once said, "Most people are bothered by those passages in Scripture which they cannot understand; but as for me, I have always noticed that the passages in Scripture which trouble me most are those which I do understand.

There are searchable compilations of his writings on religion, like [Mark Twain on Religion](http://sacred-texts.com/aor/twain/index.htm) and [The Bible According to Mark Twain](https://books.google.com/books?id=yT07SFerMvkC). You can also search Twain's letters [here](http://www.marktwainproject.org) and [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/3199/3199-h/3199-h.htm). No dice.

Comment: agree - looked at all of those places and didn't have any luck

Comment: I think Twain used to be the go-to attribution for any snark -"Sounds like something Twain would say..."

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Yes... The first link in my answer goes in to a lot of detail about that.

Comment: I'll check that out at home - away from the work firewall.